# How to communicate between two instances of the same page in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, youtube-api

My GWT application needs to upload to YouTube using browser-based upload described here http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#Browser_based_Upload
I need YouTube to redirect to the same page I am uploading video from after upload is completed, so I can inform the user that the upload is done.

For this reason, I am setting the form action like this  (ytPost is used to store both token and PostUrl received from YouTube).

form.setAction(ytPost.getPostUrl()+ "?nexturl="+Window.Location.getHref().toString());

From what I see in Eclipse, this happens in a thread called - Daemon Thread [Code server for fyiapp from Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C) on http://127.0.0.1:8888/FyiApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#tab=plan&item=69 @ _brp1HJ[BO$Y~rSZ] (Running)

The problem comes when YouTube redirects back to the same page from which I initiated the upload, but GWT instantiates a new thread called -

Daemon Thread [Code server for fyiapp from Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C) on http://127.0.0.1:8888/FyiApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#tab=plan&item=69 @ _brp1HJ[BO$Y~rSZ] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 104 in PostEditor))

As a result, even though I am technically on the “same page” code wise (GWT client side) from where I initiated the initial YouTube upload request, this page doesn’t have any state which I need to inform the user that YouTube upload is completed. I can issue Window.alert, or write to the status bar, but all the widgets are brand new.

The both threads continue to run from this point on.

What should I do to either be able to receive YouTube redirect on the same thread from which the upload was initiated or if this is impossible, how should I pass the information between two instances of the same browser page?

Answer (score 1):

What about introducing an extra parameter, finished=true | false so your "setAction" would look like:

```
form.setAction(ytPost.getPostUrl()+ "?nexturl=" +
  Window.Location.getHref().toString()+"&finished=true");
```

so that the parameter "finished=true" is passed to your page when the upload is finished and it can react on it.

Comment: Thanks you, Sasha.
My problem is not understanding how to communicate between two different threads which represent the same page.
One thread is the original one – it is sitting and waiting for an answer, and checking for extra parameters in URL string injected by YouTube upon upload completion. 
Another thread is created by GWT upon receiving GET (redirect) request from YouTube. This one has extra parameters in URL  injected by YouTube. So my question boils down to this: what should I do to pass these parameters back to my original thread where I am waiting for them?

Comment: Larisa, you can use java.util.concurrent.FutureTask to pass parameters asynchronously between threads.

That said, it may not be a bast idea to keep the main thread open while waiting the async communication. This could starve your server of threads.

Comment: I realized that I took a wrong approach. I need to have a Servlet  to catch the redirect from YouTube on the server and store the returned id of uploaded video (which is appended to URL) in the DB. In addition, I need to periodically check for this information in the DB from the page I initiated YouTube upload from. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If your problem is resolved, consider "accepting" the answer (green checkbox).